# Not able to get desired output using Tesseract Hindi Text

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am not able to get the desired output using Tesseract even after using the Devanagari script
Specifically gender(Fifth Field) and flat no. (Second Field) not able to get that
.Can someone help me with this?
Attached are both the input and output files

[image: Input1]
[image: Ouput]

Comment: Hi @https://stackoverflow.com/users/11089932/hanshirse Can you help with this